# Randbetween prevent duplicates VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing a sheet to run a draw for a sports and social club. I have used a macro. I count the number of employees and use randbetween in VBA then match to pull the name from a table. There can be 1200 employees and 400 hit of the pull a number button. I find however that I am getting repeats. Is there a way of preventing repeatsbor getting the randbetween to run again until it pulls a unique number? I am only beginner in VBA.

Comment: I just add a new line with the previous pick numbers in a list. I then used vba to make cell a2 =worksheetfuntion(randbetween(1,countemployees).      Ideally I want it to generate a random number in this range check if is already in column a if it is try another number until it gets a unique number.

Comment: Did you mean `Worksheetfunction.RandBetween`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheetfunction.randbetween

Comment: Yes sorry brax    so what I am hoping for is          x=randbetween(1,noemployees). If x = a number already in column a then try again else a1 =x.

Comment: Did you try the suggestion in the answer below?

Comment: Thanks but it's not in.vba and the comments were not great. I am hoping to do it in VBA if possible.

Answer (score 0):

use rnd + Time based value

or check out this [link](https://www.got-it.ai/solutions/excel-chat/excel-tutorial/random/how-to-use-the-randbetween-function-with-no-duplicates) for a more complete way